# When i copy the HTML from DOM to template it works, otherwise not

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have wordpress template and want to add a menu with "wp_list_pages" and a ready made script (http://www.webpulse.com.br/menuzord/index.html). When i go to the website the menu loses some elements who should be added with jquery like

```
$(menu).children("li").children("a").each(function(){
    if($(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").length > 0){
    $(this).append("<span class='indicator'>" + settings.indicatorFirstLevel + "</span>");
    }
});
```

(this is a part of the menu script).
but it will be ignored. But when i copy the source code to the template it works. Any idea what happens here? I don't really understand why the same code works when hard coded and doesn't work when included dynamically?

This is the jquery to call the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menuzord").menuzord({
        align: "left",
        scrollable: true
    });
});
```

Comment: is that code run inside `document.ready` so the elements exist? What is `menu` variable? Any errors thrown? Wordpress usually uses `jQuery.noConclict()` which will make `$` undefined

Comment: OK  any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: There is only one warning with google maps api, but when i deregister google maps the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since wordpress usually uses `jQuery.noConflict()` which removes the `$` alias from window try using the following instead of `$(document).ready(){})`

```
jQuery(function($){
   // your code here
});
```